# Old web page persists in browser

Tags: python, django, apache, browser

I built a web site with python and django which is deployed with apache 2.2.
Recently I made a huge change to the website. I just replaced the all the programs and templates and static files with the new version and restarted apache.

However, from my browser I still saw the old webpage. I then refreshed the page several times before the new page showed up. Worse, one of my colleagues still cannot access my new webpage after clearing his browser data and restarted computer. With developer tools, I found his browser got the right source html but somehow failed to show the right webpage.

I have the following questions:

1. Is this problem browser related or server related?
2. How can I ensure every browser display the right webpage?

Comment: [Should I blame cache?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Are you sure that the Django cache is not the faulty ? Are you sure you don't have a front cache (such as Varnish)?

Comment: After removing content liscense, my collegue can finally see the webpage

Comment: I don't use django cache

Comment: Have you ran the collectstatic command?

Comment: Yeah. Static files are served well

Comment: Is it possible that one browser can access new websites while another cannot